# Why shouldn't I flush mount a fan on a sloped ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, mounting, fans, slope

I have a room with a low, sloped ceiling. I planned to mount a small 20-inch, flush mount caged fan and light. The specs state that it cannot mount on a sloped ceiling.

Can anyone give me a good reason not to do it?

Comment: national electrical code says "follow manufacturer's instructions unless code more restrictive than those"

Answer (score 3):

If the fan is not designed to be mounted to swivel in line with gravity, then it will be pointing at an angle.

No fan would be designed to work like that.  If it worked at all, it would cause premature fatigue of components.

You need to follow the directions of the manufacturer !!!

Answer (score 3):

To list a few of the more obvious issues:

- The motor bearings aren't designed for side loads.
- The blades may hit the ceiling.
- The junction box isn't designed for torque loads.
- The pullchains may not function properly.
- Light kits aren't designed for side loads.
- Gravity applied asymmetrically may result in wobble, exacerbating all of the above.

Comment: If you look at pictures of *wall mounted fans* you'll see features that address exactly all of these bullet points.  Buy a suitable product.   A wall mounted fan can be mounted anywhere and pointed anywhere.  A ceiling fan can be mounted on a sloped ceiling with a rod and ball joint but in the end must point down.

Answer (score 1):

The stresses on the fan blades are very different if they're being rotated vertically rather than horizontally. Ceiling fans are designed for the latter, and since they have decent engineers, they are designed to be *just* strong enough for the horizontal use. Vertical would be equivalent to grabbing a blade and wagging it back and forth repeatedly... until it fails.

I'd suggest you look for a product designed for your application.